# Azure Powershell Cmdlets and Certificate Expiry

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am writing an Azure Deployment tool in Powershell using the PowerShell CmdLets that are provided from Microsoft.

In order to use the Azure Management CmdLets you must first associate a certificate to your subscription - typically by using the Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile command to download a pre-baked file from Azure.

This certificate has an expiry date - what happens after the expiry date?
I **assume** the CmdLets will stop working until the Certificate is refreshed.

My question is:

*How* will the CmdLets respond when the certificate as expired?
*How* will I be able to detect this in my Powershell script?

I'm finding this hard to test.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782, Service Management API does not check for certificate expiry. From this site itself:

> The Service Management API does not verify that a certificate is still valid. Authentication will succeed against an expired certificate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I did search the documentation but clearly not well enough.